# How to linearly extend the DeRahm operator $d \colon \Omega^{*}(M) \to \Omega^{*+1}(M) $

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, connections

I have two questions regarding section 1.2.5. of the following [lecture notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15_AK0HGxgYXJas46SWFxTmbNR0eCCTH2/view).

### Question 1 (Answered)

In the lecture notes, they view a differential form $\omega \in \Omega^p(M)$ as a $C^{\infty}$-antisymmetric linear map
$$
\omega \colon \underbrace{\mathfrak{X}(M) \times \cdots \times \mathfrak{X}(M)}_{p \text{ times}} \to C^{\infty}(M).
$$
They then claim that you may write
$$
d(\omega)(X_1, \ldots, X_{p+1}) = \sum_{i < j}(-1)^{i + j}\omega([X_i, X_j], X_1, \ldots, \hat X_i, \ldots, \hat X_j, \ldots, X_{p+1}) + \sum_{i = 1}^{p+1} (-1)^{i + 1}L_{X_i}(\omega(X_1, \ldots, \hat X_i, \ldots, X_{p+1})).
$$
Here the hat above the vector fields denotes that they leave that entry out. Also $L_X$ denotes the Lie derivative along the vector field $X$.

I don't see how or why this arises in this exact way. Could someone maybe give a hint as to why this is the case?

EDIT: As has been pointed out by Berci, I should clarify which definition I am using for the operator $d$. The definition I am using is that $d \colon \Omega^{\bullet}(M,E) \to \Omega^{\bullet + 1}(M,E)$ is fully characterized by

1. The operator $d \colon \Omega^0(M) = C^{\infty}(M) \to \Omega^1(M)$, is simply the differential, i.e. it is given by $df = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{d f}{d x_i} d x^i$.
2. The operator satisfies the Leibniz identity, i.e. $d(\omega \wedge \eta) = d (\omega) \wedge \eta + (-1)^{|\omega|} \omega \wedge d(\eta)$
3. $d \circ d = 0$.

Apparently, this description gives rise to a unique operator. I was under the impression that this wasn't the case for some reason. I will review this later. Thanks @Berci!

### Question 2

Using this description for differential forms, they also use this description for $E$-valued differential forms $\omega \in \Omega^p(M, E)$
$$
\omega \colon \underbrace{\mathfrak{X}(M) \times \cdots \times \mathfrak{X}(M)}_{p \text{ times}} \to \Gamma(E).
$$
They do this by replacing the Lie derivative with the connection, giving us the operator
$$
d_\nabla \colon \Omega^{\bullet}(M,E) \to \Omega^{\bullet + 1}(M,E) 
$$
This makes sense to me.
However, the author goes on and states

> Moreoever, $d_{\nabla}$ defined on $ \Omega^{\bullet}(M,E)$ is uniquely determined by what it does on the degree zero part and the fact that $d_{\nabla}$ satisfies the Leibniz identity.

I have tried proving this but to no avail. I have tried searching on StackExchange and Wikipedia for some hints, and the best that I could find was on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_differential_form) under "exterior derivative". There it is stated that it is due to **linearity** (and the Leibniz identity). What is exactly meant by that? Do they mean that I should view the space of linear operators $\Omega^{\bullet}(M,E) \to \Omega^{\bullet + 1}(M,E)$ (obeying Leibniz) obeying as a sort of vector space that has the property that its basis elements are the $d \colon \Omega^0(M,E) = \Gamma(E) \to \Omega^1(M,E)$ (which are exactly the connections on $E$)?

Thank you in advance for the hints and the help! :)

Comment: For **Q1**: this is just the definition of the $d$ operator. Or, was it defined another way?

Comment: @Berci Wasn't is the case that the $d$ operator was characterized by it satisfying the Leibniz identity, it being the differential of $0$-forms and that $d \circ d = 0$? I see that what I provided under Q1 satisfies these properties, but this does not mean that this is the *only* possible description, right? Or maybe it is?  Either way, thanks for the input! :)

Comment: In other sources this formula is taken as the definition. Maybe update the post by this definition. Try to use induction to prove that it's the unique such operator.

Comment: You can show that the definition you already know of $d$ implies the definition of the notes. It is equally easy to show that the definition from the notes implies the one you know. The trick is to let the vector fields $X_i$ be coordinate vector fields. The proof you come up with will work equally well for the vector bundle case.

Comment: Can you include in the post which Leibniz rule are you referring to?

Comment: @Arctic Char. Yes! I have just updated the post.

Comment: @Deane Thanks for the clarification, I think this is exactly what I needed fot Q1

Comment: I mean the Leibniz rule in the presence of $E$.

Comment: @ArcticChar It's the same identity: $d_{\nabla}(\omega \wedge \eta) = d_{\nabla}(\omega) \wedge \eta + (-1)^{|\omega|} \omega \wedge d_{\nabla}(\eta)$